# StringBuffer's replace method is not working as it's supposed to be

Tags: java, arrays, replace, stringbuffer

Below is a code where in if I come across the alphabet O in the array (arr), then I gotta replace the same index of array (newArr) with a "." along with its neighboring indexes i.e indexes (i,j), (i +- 1,j) and (i, j +- 1) need to be replaced with a ".".

Consider this input for array(arr):

```
6 7  
.......

...O...

.......

.......

.......

.......
```

What output should I get with the array(newArr):

```
OOO.OOO

OO...OO

OOO.OOO

OOOOOOO

OOOOOOO

OOOOOOO
```

The output I'm getting:

```
OO...OO

OO...OO

OO...OO

OO...OO

OO...OO

OO...OO
```

PS: I'm aware about the corner cases wherein if we get an O in an index which will lead to ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception. Please consider the above example.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pattern{

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

    int R= sc.nextInt(); // Takes input for Rows

    int C= sc.nextInt(); // Takes input for Coloumn

    StringBuffer[] arr= new StringBuffer[R]; // Array of type StringBuffer to which input is given.

    StringBuffer[] newArr= new StringBuffer[R]; // Array of type StringBuffer which shall be filled with alphabet "O".

    for(int i=0; i<R; i++)

        arr[i]= new StringBuffer(sc.next()); // Input given to array arr.

    StringBuffer s= new StringBuffer(); // A new stringBuffer 

    for(int i=0; i<C; i++)

        s.append("O"); // appends the required amount of alphabet O for newArr.

    Arrays.fill(newArr, s); // fills the array with s(which contains only alphabet O).

    for(int i=0; i<R; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<C; j++){
             if(arr[i].charAt(j) == 'O'){
                            newArr[i].replace(j, j+1, "."); // replaces "O" with "." in newArr.
                            newArr[i].replace(j+1, j+2, "."); // replaces "O" with "." in newArr.
                            newArr[i].replace(j-1, j, "."); // replaces "O" with "." in newArr.
                            newArr[i+1].replace(j, j+1, "."); // replaces "O" with "." in newArr.
                            newArr[i-1].replace(j, j+1, "."); // replaces "O" with "." in newArr.
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<R; i++)
        System.out.println(newArr[i]); // printing the new replaced array.
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `char[][]` in that code ? I don't see the need for `StringBuffer` here. And using `fill` put the instance in every cell, not a copy. So you end up with `s` in every cell of `newArr`, the same reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sicne you fill the `newArr` with [`Arrays.fill(Object[], Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object))

> Assigns the specified Object reference to each element of the specified array of Objects

You put the same instance in every cells. So you are working with 1 instance of `StringBuffer` here. Meaning that if you do an update in one cell, every cell will have the same update (you work with one object only)

You need to create a copy for each cell (loop yourself on the array).

```
for(int i = 0; i < newArr.length; ++i){
    newArr[i] = new StringBuffer(s.toString());
}
```

Comment: Or you do it the easy and way more efficient way and just create a 2 dimensional array. Loop over that with your current algorithm and you shouldn´t have any problems.

Comment: @AlexanderHeim I agree, I state that in a comment ;) using `char[][]` or `String[]` if needed. Immutability would prevent that problem.

Comment: Thank you guys! It helped! :)